# .htaccess, prevent hotlinking, allow big bots, allow some access and allow my own domain without adding it statically

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bots, hotlinking

1. I want to allow image crawling on my site from a couple of different bots and exclude all others.
2. I want to allow images in at least one folder to not be blocked for any request.
3. I don't want to block image requests from visitors on my own site.
4. I don't want to include my domain name in the .htaccess file for portability.

The reason I ask this here and don't simply test the following code myself is that I work on my own and have no colleges to ask or external resources to test from.  I think what I've got is correct but I find .htaccess rules extremely confusing, and I don't know what I don't even know at this point.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?bing\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?facebook\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?google\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?instagram\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?linkedin\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?reddit\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?twitter\..+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cross-origin-resources/  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.* [NC]
RewriteRule \.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|webp)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

I've tested it on [htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/#top), and looks good but does complain about the second last line when tested using the following URL: http://www.example.co.uk/poignant/foo.webp

Comment: It looks like all your `HTTP_REFERER` conditions could be combined into one: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(https?://(www\.)?(bing|facebook|google|instagram|linkedin|reddit|twitter)\..+)?$`

Comment: I realized that as well @StephenOstermiller, but I left it out of this example for now.  My real question is what does the second last line of code really do to protect a site.  I found this years ago and have been using it but I can't figure it out anymore.  Do I even need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have the logic in reverse.** As written these conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) will always be successful and the request will *always* be blocked.

You have a series of *negated* conditions that are OR'd. These would only *fail* (ie. *not* block the request) if all the conditions match, which is impossible. (eg. The `Referer` header cannot be `bing` *and* `facebook`.)

You need to remove the `OR` flag on all your `RewriteCond` directives, so they are implicitly *AND'd*.

Incidentally, the suggestion in comments from @StephenOstermiller to combine the `HTTP_REFERER` checks into one (which is a good one) is the equivalent to having the individual conditions *AND'd*, not `OR`'d (as you have posted initially).

> 1. I want to allow image crawling on my site from a couple of different bots and exclude all others.

Once you've corrected the `OR`/AND as stated above, this rule will likely allow ALL bots to *crawl* your site images because bots generally do not send a `Referer` header. These directives are not really about "crawling", they allow certain websites to display your images on their domain (ie. hotlinking). This is probably the intention, however, it's not what you are stating in point #1.

(To block bots from *crawling* your site you would need to check the `User-Agent` request header, ie. `HTTP_USER_AGENT` - which would probably be better done in a separate rule.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?bing\..+$
> ```

Minor point, but the `+$` at the end of the regex is superfluous. There's no need to match the entire `Referer` when you are only interested in the *hostname*. Although these sites probably have a [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) set that prevents the URL-path being sent (by the browser) in the `Referer` header anyway, but it is still unnecessary.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.* [NC]
> ```

In comments, you were asking what this line does. This satisfies points #3 and #4 in your list, so it is certainly needed. It ensures that the requested `Host` header (`HTTP_HOST`) matches the *hostname* in the `Referer`. So the request is coming from the same site.

The alternative is to hardcode your domain in the *condition*, which you are trying to avoid.

(Again, the trailing `.*` on the regex is unnecessary and should be removed.)

This is achieved by using an internal backreference `\1` in the regex against the `HTTP_REFERER` that matches `HTTP_HOST` in the *TestString* (first argument). The `@@` string is just an arbitrary string that does not occur in the `HTTP_HOST` or `HTTP_REFERER` server variables.

This is clearer if you expand the *TestString* to see what is being matched. For example, if you make an internal request to `https://example.com/myimage.jpg` from your homepage (ie. `https://example.com/`) then the *TestString* in the `RewriteCond` directive is:

```
example.com@@https://example.com/
```

This is then matched against the regex `^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/` (the `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* is an *operator* and is part of the argument, not the regex).

1. `([^@]*)` - the first capturing group captures `example.com` (The value of `HTTP_HOST`).
2. `@@https?://` - simply matches `@@https://` in the *TestString* (part of the `HTTP_REFERER`).
3. `\1` - this is an internal backreference. So this must match the value captured from the first capturing group (#1 above). In this example, it must match `example.com`. And it does, so there is a successful match.
4. The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* (not strictly part of the regex), negates the whole expression, so the condition is successful when the regex does *not* match.

So, in the above example, the regex matches and so the condition fails (because it's negated), so the rule is not triggered and the request is not blocked.

However, if a request is made to `https://example.com/myimage.jpg` from an external site, eg. `https://external-site.example/` then the *TestString* in the `RewriteCond` directive is:

```
example.com@@https://external-site.example/
```

Following the steps above, the regex fails to match (because `external-site.example` does not match `example.com`). The *negated* condition is therefore successful and the rule is triggered, so the request is blocked. (Unless one of the other conditions *failed*.)

Note that with the condition as written, `www.example.com` is different to `example.com`. For example, if you were on `example.com`  and you used an absolute URL to your image using `www.example.com` then the regex will fail to match and the request will be blocked. This could perhaps be incorporated into the regex, to allow for this. But this is very much an edge case and can be avoided with a canonical 301 redirect earlier in the config.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
> ```

This allows an empty (or not present) `Referer` header. You "probably" do need this. It allows bots to crawl your images. It permits direct requests to images. It also allows users who have chosen to suppress the `Referer` header to be able to view your images on *your* site.

HOWEVER, it's also possible these days for a site to set a *Referrer-Policy* that completely suppresses the `Referer` header being sent (by the browser) and so bypasses your hotlink protection.

> ```
> RewriteRule \.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|webp)$ - [F,L,NC]
> ```

Minor point, but the `L` flag is not required when the `F` flag is used (it is implied).

Are you really serving `.bmp` images?!

#### *Aside:* Sites don't necessarily "hotlink"

Some of these external sites (bing, Facebook, Google, Instagram, LinkedIn, Reddit, twitter, etc.) don't necessarily "hotlink" images anyway. They often make their own (resized/compressed) "copy" of the image instead (a bot makes the initial request to retrieve the image - with no `Referer` - so the request is not blocked).

So, explicitly permitting some of these sites in your "hotlink-protection" script might not be necessary anyway.

#### Summary

Taking the above points into consideration, the directives should look more like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?(bing|facebook|google|instagram|linkedin|reddit|twitter)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cross-origin-resources/  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|webp|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for this amazing feedback @MrWhite.  It really helps me understand better exactly how this aspect of .htaccess files works.  As for the .bmp, lol.  That's just part of a generic string of objects that I want to be able to protect but probably will never be needed.  I'm going to post an answer to my own question below, summarising my final solution and a couple of references that I found after posting to help others.